# send image and text at the same time flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to upload image and other types of data like string and integer with the HTTP post method at the same time. but i got error code said that json cant encode image file, i have this code on flutter :

```
static Future<ApiReturnValue<Asset>> addAsset(Asset asset, File imageFile,
  {http.Client client}) async {
client ??= http.Client();

String url = baseUrl + 'asset';
var uri = Uri.parse(url);

var response = await client.post(
  uri,
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer ${User.token}"
  },
  body: jsonEncode(
    <String, dynamic>{
      "name": asset.name,
      "condition": asset.condition,
      "purchase_date": asset.purchaseDate,
      "price": asset.price,
      "location": asset.location,
      "description": asset.description,
      "image": imageFile,
    },
  ),
);

if (response.statusCode != 200) {
  return ApiReturnValue(message: "Add item failed, please try again");
}

var data = jsonDecode(response.body);

Asset value = Asset.fromJson(data['data']['asset']);
return ApiReturnValue(value: value);
```

}

is that any way that I can send image and text on HTTP post request at the same time without separating the image using multipart request?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps base64-encode the image so that it can be embedded in the json? would not be as efficient as sending it as a separate part.

Comment: ok i'll try , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include an image in the request body for POST, normally you have to convert it into a multipart file, then include it in the body as formdata. This required the server to expect the multipart file within the formdata itself when receive the image from client.

I'd like to recommend this package name [dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) for you. It supports MultipartFile, FormData and other powerful helper classes.

Here's an example:

```dart
static Future<bool> sendImage(String imagePath) async {
    try {
      final content = MultipartFile.fromFile(imagePath);
      final contentType = 'multipart/form-data';
      final Response response = await dio.post('$BASE_URL/$images',
          data: FormData.fromMap({'file': content}),
          options: Options(contentType: contentType));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    } catch (error) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

You can read more on the [FormData](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio#sending-formdata) here

Answer (score 0):

You can have your asset data in the request header:

```dart
  var response = await client.post(
    uri,
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer ${User.token}",
      "asset-data": jsonEncode(
        <String, dynamic>{
          "name": asset.name,
          "condition": asset.condition,
          "purchase_date": asset.purchaseDate,
          "price": asset.price,
          "location": asset.location,
          "description": asset.description
        },
      ),
    },
    body: imageFile.readAsBytesSync(),
  );
```

This will need you to modify your server-side code to read from the header.